# two forms on one page - disable one of them

Tags: jquery, forms

I have two HTML forms on one page. I'd like to enable the second form after the first one is sent and checked (before that the second form should be disabled). Then I'd like to have enable both of them. How to do it in jQuery or any language?

Comment: I think you probably need some server side script for that.

Comment: try to create the form dynamically and then submit them

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: @user have tried something post it

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a rough idea so you can get started on it.

1. You have [an Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) with each form placed in it.
2. You write a small javascript to disable the later parts of the form until the previous parts have been submitted and returned a value.
3. You submit each section of the form via [AJAX requests](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and have your server return the value your javascript needs to progress to the next section.

If you write some code and get stuck, you can ask a specific question on how to get your code working and you'll likely to get some helpful answers.

Always search check through similar questions first as there will likely be several already answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>disabled demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input name="email" disabled="disabled">
  <input name="id">
</form>

<span style="float:left;" id="form1">
    <form action='logout.php' method='POST'>           
        <input type='submit' value='Logout' />      
    </form>   
</span>
<span style="float:right;" id="form2">
    <form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>     
        <input type='submit' value='Change password' />       
    </form>
</span>


<script>
$("#form1").prop( "disabled", true );
//....put your script here
</script>

</body>
</html>
```